# Appending a constant cstring to my own String class object

Tags: c++, string, class, append

I am writing my own String class and having problems with the append function. It takes a contant cstring as argument and appends it at the end of the String calling it.

The function has the following prototype:

```
void append(char *str );
```

**Expected Working:**

```
String s1("John");

s1.append(" Doe");

s1.display();
```

**The result should be:**

```
John Doe
```

**What am i getting?**

```
John
```

**What am i doing?**

- char * data is the data member of my String class.

  1. Copying the contents of **data** into **temp**.
  2. Redeclaring the **data** having the size equal to temp+CStringToBeAppended+1
  3. Now, copying the content of **temp** into the new **data**.
  4. Copying the contents of **CStringToBeAppended** into the new **data** starting at the position of **strlen(temp)**.

**Here is the function i have so far:**

```
//char * data is the data member of my String class.

void append(char* str)
{

    char *temp = new char[strlen(data)+1];

    for (int i=0; data[i] != '\0'; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    len = strlen(temp) + strlen(str);

    data = new char [len+1];

    for (int i=0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++)
        data[i] = temp[i];

    for (int i=strlen(temp); str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        data[i] = str[i];


    delete [] temp;
}
```

Comment: Show how you allocated memory for data in your class?

Comment: It's there as:    len = strlen(temp) + strlen(str);

    data = new char [len+1];

Comment: Your first allocation is pointless.  And side note: that param should be `const char *`, not `char *`.

Comment: Why temp, why not allocate strlen(data) + strlen(str) + 1 and swap that pointer with data, why the memory leak?

Comment: @WhozCraig: temp pointer has the scope restricted inside the function. You are write about the `const char *`.

Comment: @DieterLücking: data is my class data member which is being destroyed by the destructor. I couldn't get what you meant by "swap that pointer with data".

Comment: @FaizanSaleem Making a straight up copy of the very thing you're about to throw away isn't needed. Allocate space for *both* strings, copy `data` in first, then keep copying `str` in where `data` stopped, then terminate. retain new string, cleanup old string, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made few changes

1. `Null` terminate `temp` after you copy data
2. Used variable `j` as a starting point in `data`. Assigned j with strlen(temp)
3. Starting positing of `data` is replaced with `j++` from `i`

> ```
> void stringx::appendx(char* str)
> {
>     int x = strlen(data);
>     char *temp = new char[strlen(data)+1];
>
>     int i;
>     for ( i=0; data[i] != '\0'; i++)
>         temp[i] = data[i];
>     temp[i] = '\0';                             //<----Change 1
>
>     len = strlen(temp) + strlen(str);
>
>     data = new char [len+1];
>     memset(data,0,strlen(data)+1);
>
>     for (int i=0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++)
>         data[i] = temp[i];
>
>     int j=strlen(temp);                        //<----Change 2
>     for (int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
>         data[j++] = str[i];                    //<----Change 3
>
>
>     delete [] temp;
> }
> ```

Comment: Fyi, this flat-out leaks the original `data` memory allocation, and *still* makes an unneeded copy of the original `data` string.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Yes Right. He must delete before reallocating anything again. yes I  agree no need to temp copying..

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes an unnecessary copy of the incoming data string, further enhanced by the copy-through termination logic. This is what you're trying to do.

Assuming `data` is **not** null and **is** properly 0-terminated:

```
void append(const char *str)
{
    if (!(str && *str))
        return;

    char *final = new char[ strlen(str) + strlen(data) + 1 ], *dst = final;

    // copy in lhs
    const char *src = data;
    while (*src)
        *dst++ = *src++;

    // copy in rhs
    while (*str)
        *dst++ = *str++;
    *dst = 0;

    // swap pointers
    std::swap(data, final);

    // throw out prior result
    delete [] final;
}
```

And you can make this *considerably* more efficient by keeping a separate member of the allocate size of your `data` member (`data_len`). Even more so using `std::copy()` or `memcpy` to move the data, since you already know the lengths. Otherwise your appends are nothing more than [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) dressed up in a fancy class. A modified version using `std::copy()` be below. I leave managing a `data_len` member along side `data` to you

```
void append(const char *str)
{
    if (!(str && *str))
        return;

    size_t dlen = strlen(data);
    size_t slen = strlen(str);      
    char *final = new char[ dlen + slen + 1 ];

    std::copy(data, data+dlen, final);
    std::copy(str, str+slen+1, final+dlen);
    std::swap(data,final);
    delete [] final;
}
```

Comment: Your logic is simply awesome for me. I would love to upvote but i can't as for now. Actually, i wanted to accept both the answers but as for the other answer, i am accpeting it for now and going to adopt working with pointer from now on. Thanks

Comment: @FaizanSaleem Sok, no worries, but if you adopt the other answer you may want to fix the memory leak it has (unless the author fixed it, which as of this post has not happened yet). The same leak was in your original code as well.